# Link to meta is http in the main site's ask questions page

Tags: bug, asking-questions, ssl

In the main site [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), in the **How to Ask** side bar, the link to meta site is `http://` only.

The tip in the side bar is:

> If your question is about this website, [ask it on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) instead.

This can be update to `https://`, in other sites the link is mapped with `https://`.

Comment: Still broken 5 months later. Also, I'd consider this a [meta-tag:bug], since [all internal links on the SE network *should* be using HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time). (Also, as a gratuitous plug, [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) includes a client-side fix for this and other similar missing HTTPS bugs on SE. Or you can just use [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).)